# domain name in browser bar changes to IP after loading

Tags: nginx, server, digital-ocean

I created a new domain on 1und1.de which is called medifaktor.de
Then I added the nameservers of digital ocean:

- ns1.digitalocean.com
- ns2.digitalocean.com
- ns3.digitalocean.com

[image]

the nginx config file looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name www.medifaktor.de;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    error_page 404 /index.php;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
    }
}
```

when I now want to access the domain it works, but the URL gets exchanged with the IP address still. How can I change this?

The access.log contains:

```
185.17.207.244 - - [12/May/2016:13:10:48 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.94 Safari/537.36"
185.17.207.244 - - [12/May/2016:13:10:49 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.94 Safari/537.36"
74.91.18.46 - - [12/May/2016:13:11:01 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 612 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0)"
```

Comment: "Gets exchanged with". Do you mean in the browser address bar?

Comment: What's in the access log?

Comment: i added the output of access.log in the questin

Comment: Tried it just now and did not see a rewrite, but it just came up to the default nginx start page.

Comment: yep.. thats fine as there is only a start page. but what do you see in your address bar?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111767/discussion-between-sesc360-and-stark).

Comment: i use 1and1.com for the domain, put the digital ocean name servers in, and redirected the domain to my droplet URL. If I change this to the url name, I get an error that too many redirects would happen